# How to start an Activity in specific coordinates

Tags: java, android, canvas, kotlin

My Activity has a Canvas with both width and height equal to 6000. When I start the Activity the upper left coordinate of my screen is (0,0) so screen' center is about (30,60). **What I want is start the Activity with coordinates (3000,3000) in the center of screen**
[image: just an example]

any solution?

**Update 1:**

I used this Kotlin code:

```
var fondo = Lienzo(this) //fondo is the Canvas View (6000,6000)
val scrollV = ScrollView(this)
val hscrollV = HorizontalScrollView(this)
scrollV.addView(fondo)
hscrollV.addView(scrollV)
layaout1.addView(hscrollV) //layaout1 is a RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

More code would be nice since I cannot see where you are declaring the position but if you are hard-coding the coordinates, I would suggest instead of using the same variables for width and height and just putting them in the coordinates /2 so if your variables are width and height, it should be kind of like this depending on what you are using:

```
.setPosition(width/2, height/2);
```

If this isn't useful then please provide more info or more code to see where your mistake is :)

Comment: I did not declare position, because I don't know how to do it.
`fondo` is the Canvas View(6000,6000)
I don't know where to plece `.setPosition(width/2, height/2);`, in layout?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Canvases work in Android.  You don't declare how big you want it to be and it magically scales to the screen.  If you're in the View's onDraw function, the Canvas passed in is the size of the View, in physical pixels.  You need to scale your drawing to it.  If you're drawing to an offscreen bitmap first and then blitting that to the screen, its your job to scale the bitmap via a matrix when you blit it.  Also, in Android the coordinate system is 0,0 as the upper left hand corner. Unless it greatly eases your drawing I suggest you not fight it.

However you could use a matrix transformation on the Canvas to change that.  First you'd want to scale the matrix by 6000/view.getHeight() in the y and 6000/view.getWidth() in the x.  Then you'd want to translate it by -3000 in the x and -3000 in the y.  That should scale it to the view and move origin to center.